# Switch SIM cards

Tags: iphone

I attempted to upgrade to ISO 9 and now phone is locked on slide to upgrade screen. Can I take out the SIM card on my iPhone 4s and put it into my old iPhone 4 and will it work?

Comment: If my answer helped you, please click the checkmark to the left of my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, so long as the iPhone 4 is on the same carrier as the 4S, it will work.

To fix the "Slide To Upgrade" bug, see [Apple's support instructions.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205239)